# How to keep EC2 instance logged in after RDP is closed

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I've done everything I can to try to fix this.

I've tried to do the command
tscon 2 /dest:console
in CMD, which disconnects RDP without you pressing X. It still logs out. I went to the group policy and modified EVERYTHING I can. I've read a lot of tutorials on how to disable this and nothing happens when I try to do it.

I am trying to run a stream on this EC2 server and I've done everything and spent the last 6 hours trying to fix it. It's annoying. Can someone please try to help me fix this? I've even gone into group policy editor and tried that and that didn't even work.

Could it be because of EC2? I don't know.